# Custom Post types and Custom fields in Wordpress Multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I'm new to Wordpress Multisite and I wonder if it's possible to define a set of Custom Post Types (Films, Categories, and Actors) and a set of Custom Fields (i.e. a Film has a trailer field, actors, and a category) for every new site a make for the network.

I need to be able to create new sites and all of them must come preconfigured with the CPT and CF I said.

Is it possible with Wordpress MU or should I find another solution?

Comment: Will they be sharing the same theme?

Comment: yes, they will!

Answer (score 1):

Provided they're all using the same theme, you could declare each of the custom post types in functions.php in the parent theme (in case you have child themes). Since multi-sites share the same plugins and themes, the custom post types will be registered for all sites using that theme.

The custom fields are a bit different. You could use a plugin like [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) which I do recommend, but which would require activating for each site. If you wanted those custom fields to be available immediately for use on the post edit screen, you could add `add_post_meta()` for each of your necessary fields to the post with ID 1. All instances of Wordpress will have a post with ID 1, the default post. These fields will then be "pre-registered". Note that I'm leaving out the "Categories" post type and field you mention, because Category is already a Wordpress taxonomy, and it might confuse users. This is not an ideal solution, but it works. I've had to do it when pre-populating custom fields for a dental office software that automatically deployed a Wordpress instance.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_custom_post_types' );
function create_custom_post_types() {

  register_post_type( 'films',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Films' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Film' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields' )
    )
  );

  register_post_type( 'actors',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Actors' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Actor' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields' )
    )
  );
}

// Check if the post meta has been added to our default post. 
// If not, add our post_meta to make it available.

if(!get_post_meta( 1, 'trailer_for_film') ) {
  add_post_meta( 1, 'trailer_for_film', 'default trailer', true );
  add_post_meta( 1, 'actors', 'default actor', true );
}
```